# Location Aware Exception After upgrading to Android Studio 3.1 - Build Failed

Tags: android, android-studio

I am facing an issue of build getting failed. I recently upgraded my android studio. And the look and feel has good changes in the IDE. But there is something I am stuck at. After making a few changes in the existing code I am trying to run the project and the build always fails with an error (Look at the image)

[image]

I tried to look for a lot of possible solutions and didn't find anything correct.
Help me out someone :p

Answer (score 6):

Here you go with a simple and funny solution:

[image]

just follow the image.

Have fun. Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

Check for **local.properties** is there any key missing or some property is missing at the time of update it might got reset