# Android Studio: Compilation Failed: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, location-aware

I am working on an application. My app is running perfectly. Don't know what goes wrong and I am continuously getting this error when running the app. I tried almost each and everything written on internet but failed to solve the error. I am attaching screenshot of my error as well as my gradle's  also. Please help. It almost wasted my 2 days.

[Gradle Configuration Part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Scaj9.png)

[image]

[Gradle Configuration Part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iB5ec.png)

[image]

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4e4L4.png)

[image]

Comment: check this one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49751844/location-aware-exception-after-upgrading-to-android-studio-3-1-build-failed

Comment: A wee bit late here, but it'll be good to know for any one who ends up here what the cause was. There's a good chance you had compilation errors in your code. Maybe a missed semicolon or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

To flesh out Storesource's comment, right click on your project's root in Android Studio and then click Analyze>Inspect Code. You'll almost certainly have at least one error, which you can then stamp out and successfully rebuild.